WebStorm Tailwind not always suggest
Tailwind suggestion does not work inside {} brackets or if using cn function:
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from 'clsx';

import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) { return twMerge(clsx(inputs)); }




But if I move a caret from the right side you can see suggestions.
I want to always see the suggestions on Ctrl + Space (in any position of my caret).

Where is the cn version? and you mind sharing your package.json & tailwind.config.js?
